# PHP array_unique not behaving as expected

Tags: php, xml, array-unique

I have a little PHP script I am running.
It basically puts the content of an XML file and assigns it to a variable.
I then create an array containing all the XML tags and values I want to use, using the parse array function from LIB_parse.php:

```
function parse_array($string, $beg_tag, $close_tag)
{
    preg_match_all("($beg_tag(.*)$close_tag)siU", $string, $matching_data);
        //preg_match_all("($beg_tag(.*)($beg_tag(.*)$close_tag)+(.*)$close_tag)siU", $string, $matching_data);
    return $matching_data[0];
}
```

This all works well.

But what I would like to do is remove all duplicates from this now huge array.
I have done it through Excel and I know it should give me 3945 XML tags and values.
But when I run the array through array_unique, it returns me an array with 3945 lines but only about 400 of them actually contain the XML tags and values I want, the others are blank lines.

```
$value = file_get_contents("myXMLfile.xml");
$array = parse_array($value, "<marker", "/>");
$clean_array = array_unique($array);
```

I then use a loop to put the values of the array into another XML file.

Any ideas?

Sorry the length of this.

Comment: What does `parse_array` do?

Comment: Okay, I found the parse_array function and edited it into the question.

Comment: Creates an array from all the strings that match the criteria given in the call. So in this case it creates an array, in which each entry is a string starting with <marker and ending with /> that is found in $value.

Comment: Could the tags simply be displaying wrong in your web browser?  Check View Source, if you're looking at the results in your browser.

Comment: I don't look at the resulting file through a browser. I put the results in an XML file. There are certain tags and values that appear as expected (about 400) but all the other lines in the file are blank (like putting \n).

Comment: And if I don't use the array_unique function I can export the $array array and get the 39000 XML tags and values all displaying correctly

Comment: I think it's a good idea to create a small test case with 2 to 4 lines of XML, and then dump the content that you get from `parse_array()` and analyze the result. It might not be what you think it is - and nobody else can recreate your case because you haven't given any sample data.

Comment: I will give it a shot with a smaller sample, and if I get nothing I will post samples here tomorrow.